# looking for application of construction of valuation sub ring of a valuation ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a domain with $Frac(R)=K$. $R$ is called valuation ring of field $K$ if $\forall a,b\in R$ either $aR\subset bR$ or $bR\subset aR$.

Let $R$ be a valuation ring of field $K$. Let $p$ be maximal ideal of $R$. Denote $R^\star$ as a valuation ring of field $\frac{R}{p}$. Let $R'=\{x\in R\vert x(\mod p)\in R^\star\}$. Then $R'$ is a valuation ring of $K$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ What is the application of above statement? It seems this incorporates both residue field and elements of $R$. I could not see any application to number ring settings.

Comment: I don't know if you made a typo, but clearly $R'=R$ with your definition.

Comment: @CaptainLama Sorry. I should have written that $R^\star$ is any valuation ring of field $R/p$ instead.

Comment: No, I think the current statement is the one intended.

Comment: You meant $p$ is a prime ideal, $R/p$ is a VR of $Frac(R/p)$ (its ideals have a total order) and $R' = (R-p)^{-1} R$ is a VR of $Frac(R)$. Try with $R = F[[y]]+xF((y))[[x]]$ and  $p=xF((y))[[x]]$

Comment: @reuns Nagata's book says $p$ is maximal ideal. Yes for any prime ideal $p$ $R/p$ is valuation ring induced valuation structure directly from $R$ itself. What I have in my mind is the following similar to your example. Consider $Q_p[[x]]$ valuation ring. $Z_p\subset Q_p$ valuation ring as residue field of $Q_p[[x]]$. Then I have $Z_p+xQ_p[[x]]\subset Q_p[[x]]$ ring $R'$ which I think it is the case.

Comment: @reuns In particular, I think my example indicates that $R'$ may not even be noetherian and hence not even DVR. So I do not know any geometric examples coming from this construction.

Comment: Ah ok you meant the reverse map, if $R^*$ is a VR of $Frac(R/p)$ then $R'= \{ x\in (R-p)^{-1} R, x\bmod p \in R^*\}$ is a VR of $Frac(R)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construction corresponds to the composition of valuations: the valuation ring $R$ corresponds to a valuation $v: K^\times\to \Gamma$ on the fraction field, and $R^\star$ to a valuation $w:\kappa^\times \to G$ where $\kappa=R/p$ is the residue field.

Then $R'$ corresponds by definition to the valuation $w\circ v$ on $K$.

It is often use for induction processes, if for instance the value group is $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (you can think of $k((X_1,\dots,X_n))$ for instance), then it can be decomposed as a composition of $n$ valuations with value group $\mathbb{Z}$, which are easier to work with.